# raster: Modifications of the methods in resample() function

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I’ve like to know the possibility of make some modifications in `resample()` function in `raster` package. First, in `"bilinear"` method by default is assigns a weighted average of the four nearest cells, and I’ll like to change for different number nearest cells, too, is possible? Second, is it possible too to create the mean method to calculate the arithmetic average of the n nearest cells too?
  For example, in the first case for 25 cells: `resample (myraster, myresolution, window=matrix (nrow=5,nol=5), method="bilinear")` and in the second case: `resample (myraster, myresolution, window=matrix (nrow=5,nol=5), fun=mean)`.

Comment: What are the five or six nearest cells to a cell? A cell has four nearest neighbours (NSEW) and then another four next-nearest at the diagonals.

Comment: Because in four nearest neighbours I have a total of 9 cells (four nearest neighbours and then another four next-nearest at the diagonals) and I like to explore too 25 and 49 cells.

Comment: Can you write down *mathematically* the transformation you want to do from source cells in one raster to target cell locations based on the target raster?

Comment: I like the central cell and it as 24 and 49 surrounding cells, in my example I've something like in the first case for 25 cells: resample (myraster, myresolution, window=matrix (nrow=5,nol=5), method="bilinear") and in the second case: resample (myraster, myresolution, window=matrix (nrow=5,nol=5), fun=mean).

Comment: You can use the focal function in the raster package to write whatever custom filter you like

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do all that, but you can use the focal function on the input data prior to using resample.